# How do I input data into <input> form using PHP?

Tags: php, automation

Okay, basically, I have a large list of phone numbers in a text file and I need to submit them all into a website by copy and pasting the phone number into the input form on the website and hit submit. Now, how can I automate this using PHP? I have no access to the website with input form.

Comment: You want to know how to...generate the form? Or how to access the data submitted in/by the form? I'm sorry, but I don't understand what 'list' you're referring to. If you can clarify your question I'll try and be helpful, though =)

Comment: Please elaborate. what is your list? Is it local or server generated? Where are you submitting the form?

Comment: Maybe you should try unit testing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the phone numbers are stored 1 per line in the file, you can use [`file()`](http://php.net/file) to open it and you'll have an array of phone numbers.

If they are stored some other way, you can use [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/file_get_contents) and [`explode()`](http://php.net/explode) the numbers into an array.

Loop over the array and use [cURL](http://php.net/curl) to post the numbers to the website.

Answer (score 1):

Loop through the text file and use Curl to fill in / submit the form?

http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/sending-post-form-data-with-php-curl.html

Sorry I'm not really a PHP coder...

Answer (score 1):

If you're not tied to PHP, and can use Perl, use WWW::Mechanize.

http://search.cpan.org/dist/WWW-Mechanize/

Comment: Yeah, but this doesn't answer the question. He asked specifically about how to do this with PHP.